# Python openpyxl switch between spreadsheets in one workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

I can see all the sheet names when i use

wb.get_sheet_names()

now i would like to rename all the sheets one after the other to numbers i.e first sheet to 1, second sheet to 2 and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: use `enumerate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each sheet and set the title to whatever you want.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
counter = 0

for sheet in sheets:
    ss_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    ss_sheet.title = str(counter)
    wb.save("file.xlsx")
    counter+= 1
```

Comment: sorry there's been a typo. edited my post,  run  this

Comment: @AkhilKodicherla did it work? share if it is any other problem?

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks. why did str make a difference?

Comment: .title accepts a string to be passed for the name of the sheet. Please accept it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
work_book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheets = work_book.get_sheet_names()
name = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
index = 0

for sheet in sheets:
    sheetname = work_book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    sheetname.title = str(name[index])
    work_book.save("renamed.xlsx")
    index += 1
```